# mvc - applying css class to div if someone click on that div without using javascript or jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on an MVC4 Application

```
@{
    var = mydivID;
}

<div id="mydivID"></div>
```

If someone click on mydiv or when it's active then add css class="active"

Like This:

Before someone click on mydiv = `<div id="mydivID"></div>`

After someone click on mydiv = `<div id="mydivID" class="active"></div>`

i don't want to use javascript or jQuery.

Please help me.... Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use javascript?

Comment: If you don't want to use javascript then the only way is by resending the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't dynamically change the contents of the DOM without JavaScript. Your only other alternative is a full new request cycle.

**View**

```
@{
    var active = ViewBag.Active as bool? ?? false;
}

<a href="@Url.Action("ThisAction", "ThisController", new { divClicked = true })">
    <div id="mydivID" class="@(active ? "active" : "")"></div>
</a>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ThisAction(bool? divClicked)
{
    ViewBag.Active = divClicked.HasValue ? divClicked : false;    
    return View();
}
```

Bonus points for using a proper model instead of ViewBag, but this illustrates the idea.

If you have multiple divs and want any of them to be clickable, you could try assigning them different IDs and passing the ID of the div into the action (and then the ViewBag) instead.

Comment: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'divClicked' of non-nullable type 'System.Boolean' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Explore(Boolean)' in 'Controller'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: The above expects you to pass a bool and will error if you don't, so that's probably on the initial load? I'll update my answer with an alternative.